# prepareforsegue method throws exception

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

In my app there is a `UITableView` showing `Core Data` objects. When the user taps on a row, a detail view of the selected object must be shown. The detail view is defined at EditToDoItemViewController. There is also an `UIButton` which opens another view to add a new object, `AddToDoItemViewController`.

I am using a `Storyboard`. One `segue` connects the `UIButton` to `AddToDoItemViewController`, its `identifier` is `addToDoItem`. Another `segue` connects the cell to `EditToDoItemViewController` and its `identifier` is `editItem`.
This is the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addToDoItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;
        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItem.todoDueDate = [NSDate date];
        addToDoItemViewController.addToDoItem = addToDoItem;

          }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editItem"]){
        EditToDoItemViewController *editToDoItemViewController = (EditToDoItemViewController*)self.navigationController.topViewController;
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ToDoItem *editToDoItem = (ToDoItem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
        editToDoItemViewController.editToDoItem = editToDoItem;

    }

}
```

The first segue works fine, but the second segue throws an expection:

```
2014-02-09 00:17:31.851 DidIt[474:a0b] -[ToDoItemsTableViewController setEditToDoItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a90e60
2014-02-09 00:17:31.980 DidIt[474:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ToDoItemsTableViewController setEditToDoItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a90e60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ad65e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018598b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b73903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01ac690b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01ac64ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   DidIt                               0x0000621e -[ToDoItemsTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 942
    6   UIKit                               0x00afc06c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 156
    7   UIKit                               0x00afc0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    8   UIKit                               0x006a9775 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1453
    9   UIKit                               0x006a9924 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    10  UIKit                               0x006ad908 __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x005e4183 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    12  UIKit                               0x005e412e _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    13  UIKit                               0x005e3f5a _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01a9e4ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01a9e41f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7c344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7bac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01a7b8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x038e79e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x038e7809 GSEventRun + 104
    21  UIKit                               0x005c7d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    22  DidIt                               0x0001e02d main + 141
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x02112725 start + 0
    24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I need your help to identify the issue...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message

```
-[ToDoItemsTableViewController setEditToDoItem:]: unrecognized selector ...
```

tells you that on the

```
editToDoItemViewController.editToDoItem = editToDoItem;
```

line, `editToDoItemViewController` is not an instance of `EditToDoItemViewController`, 
as you expect, but an instance of `ToDoItemsTableViewController`. And this looks wrong:

```
EditToDoItemViewController *editToDoItemViewController =
     (EditToDoItemViewController*)self.navigationController.topViewController;
```

It probably should be

```
EditToDoItemViewController *editToDoItemViewController =
     (EditToDoItemViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
```

Comment: I have substituted the wrong looking line of code with your proposed line of code, and the same exception is thrown. The segue at the Storyboard is from the cell to the viewController, is it right that way?

Comment: @mvasco: That sounds correct. But if I understand your question correctly, the destination of the segue should be a EditToDoItemViewController.

Comment: yes, it is, the tableView is on ToDoItemsTableViewController, and the detail view is EditTodoItemViewController. On the title bar of ToDoItemsTableViewController is the button that uses the first if statement at prepareforSegue method. Tapping on the selected object row, should launch the second if statement of prepareforSegue method and should show EditToDoItemViewController, but the exceptions is thrown instead.

Comment: @mvasco: That looks as if you did not create the segue correctly.

Comment: I have removed it and created again. I have detected that if I connect directly the segue from cell to EditToDOViewController, no exception is thrown, but if I connect the cell to the embed in navigation controller, the exception is thrown, but using the first case, no title bar is shown...?

Comment: @mvasco: Is your initial table view embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes,it is  embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: @mvasco: It is difficult to see where the problem is. Perhaps you can create a "Master-Detail" application in Xcode. That has a table view with a push segue to a detail view. Then you can compare that with your storyboard.

Comment: @mvasco: You are welcome. Just a final note: Your first transition looks also "suspicious". Normally, that would also be `AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];`.